# How to export datatable with additional text?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a requirement to add some additional text to a table excel (and pdf) export. It's basically a string in my model containing some information about parameters that were used to run a report. I am using Datatables and here is my code snippet from document ready function:

```
$('#npsOverallSummaryTable').DataTable({
            "aaSorting": [],
            "scrollX": true,
            "colReorder": true,
            "fixedHeader": true,
            "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            select: true,
            dom: 'Bfrt',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    text: 'Copy to clipboard'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Excel'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    text: 'PDF',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'A3'
                },
                'colvis'

            ],
            "columns": [
            null,
            { className: "text-right" },
            { className: "text-right" },
            { className: "text-right" },
            { className: "text-right" },
            { className: "text-right" }
            ]
        });
```

So far I had the idea to utilize the table footer which I am not using right now, but when I placed one element with colspan="6", on the Excel export I got my text 6 times (once in each cell) which is not what I'm looking for. I also tried to just put it in normal element inside the footer but then it messes up the formatting as it extends the column width to the length of the text.

I guess I am just looking for nice and clean way to include that information in the excel/pdf export. Just to mention, the website is mvc .net with bootstrap if that's relevant at all here. Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**: I have condensed the required information and placed it into the file name of the export, however I'm still on lookout if there is a better solution out there.